# How to get this terrible summation/product to run in Mathematica?

Tags: function-construction, summation

I've come across this formula and have no idea where to even start. (My assumption here is that $m,n$ are known and input into the expression to arrive at an answer.)

$$f(m,n) = \sum_{\substack{0 \leq a_{1} \leq m \\ 0 \leq a_{2} \leq m \\ ... \\ 0 \leq a_{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \leq m}} \lbrack (m-a_{1}+2)2^{a_{1}-2} \prod ^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor -1} _{i=1} (m-a_{i+1}+2)(a_{i}+1)2^{|a_{i+1}-a_{i}|-2} \rbrack$$

I don't even know where to begin on coding this. I'm stuck at multiple summation indices and haven't yet found a help thread that made sense to me. I'd appreciate any and all help.

Comment: How exactly is this expected to work, since the *a* in the sum cover subscript to floor[n/2]-1, yet in the product *a* with subscript up to floor[n/2] is used? A link to the source would be nice.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: My mistake, @ciao, it should be a subscript floor[n/2] in the sum. It's fixed now.

Comment: But, still no reference on where you encountered this sum? Anyway: `Table[Sum[(m - K[1] + 2) 2^(K[1] - 2) Product[(m - K[i + 1] + 2) (K[i] + 1) 2^(Abs[K[i + 1] - K[i]] - 2), {i, Quotient[n, 2] - 1}], Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{K[k], 0, m}, {k, Quotient[n, 2]}]]], {m, 2, 5}, {n, 2, 5}]`

Comment: @J.M. - yes, I'm more curious about part 1 - looks to be something combinatorial, but rings no bells.

Comment: @ciao, right; I did not post an answer, as I have a funny feeling that this is the least efficient method for whatever the hell the OP wants to compute. Now if only there was a ref...

Comment: The ref is my original research that I'm still conducting, which I am wary about posting online. Thank you so much for your help, though, I will definitely put it to good use. :)

Comment: If you understood and are able to explain how the snippet I gave works, consider answering your own question.